# Объясните постановку тире в предложениях

Tags: пунктуация

Можно ли как-нибудь обосновать постановку тире в предложениях: после **причем,**  **например, и, то есть** и перед **что**. Или они поставлены с нарушениями правил русского языка?

1) *Осень принесла новый виток напряженности и противостояния нижегородцев и городских властей. ПРИЧЕМ – с полного попустительства самой власти.*

2) *Осталось смахнуть слезу умиления да вздохнуть с чувством глубокого удовлетворения… Вот только мешает что-то. НАПРИМЕР – полная безнаказанность за незаконные выходки «несистемной оппозиции», возглавляющей жителей.*

3) *Хотя в близлежащих домах живёт несколько сотен человек. ТО ЕСТЬ – видео смотрят сами участники съемок да их заказчики.*

4) *Самое омерзительное, что за всей этой вакханалией стоят персонажи, хорошо известные как правоохранительным органам, так и горожанам – своей неуёмной разрушительной энергией, своей плохой репутацией. **И** – своими судимостями.*

5) *Получил он два года условно, но по уголовной статье. Говорят, хотели вообще невменяемым признать, но покровители решили – ЧТО это перебор.*

Answer (score 2):

Тире, действительно, интонационные, журналисты часто грешат такими для резкого подчёркивания отдельных мыслей. Такой рубленый стиль присущ особенно публицистам. Это нельзя назвать ошибкой, хотя объяснить иногда трудно,но возможно, для этого нужно почувствовать накал страстей и "въехать" в суть проблемы. Интонационное тире может быть поставлено в любом месте, где автор считает необходимым выделить словесную группу.У Чехова вот тоже трудно объяснить: Я вас спрашиваю: рабочим - нужно платить? Оснований для тире нет, только одно - пауза в речи, подчёркивающая сразу два слова - "рабочим" и "нужно".

1)"Осень принесла новый виток напряженности и противостояния нижегородцев и городских властей. ПРИЧЕМ – с полного попустительства самой власти."

Тире в парцеллированной конструкции, о которых много спорили, можно ли их относить к неполным предложениям. Если рассмотреть как неполное, то тире может быть воспринято как замена пропущенной словесной группы: ПРИЧЕМ (принесла новый виток напряжённости) с полного попустительства самой власти."

2)"Осталось смахнуть слезу умиления да вздохнуть с чувством глубокого удовлетворения… Вот только мешает что-то. НАПРИМЕР – полная безнаказанность за незаконные выходки «несистемной оппозиции», возглавляющей жителей."

Похожая ситуация с тире вместо пропущенного "мешает".

3)"Хотя в близлежащих домах живёт несколько сотен человек. То есть  – видео смотрят сами участники съемок да их заказчики." Тире вместо паузы, предупреждающей,что потом последует нечто интересное и неожиданное (здесь речь как раз о разоблачении заказчиков акции)

4)Самое омерзительное, что за всей этой вакханалией стоят персонажи, хорошо известные как правоохранительным органам, так и горожанам – своей неуёмной разрушительной энергией, своей плохой репутацией. И – своими судимостями.

Здесь тоже парцеллированная конструкция,тире поставлено, чтобы подчеркнуть неожиданное разоблачение персонажа - его судимость.

5)Получил он два года условно, но по уголовной статье. Говорят, хотели вообще невменяемым признать, но покровители решили – что это перебор.

Всё это же интонационное тире для разделения предложения на 2 части, чтобы подчеркнуть, что это именно покровители повлияли на решение суда и что их мнение, что это перебор, вызывает понимающую  издевательскую усмешку.

В общем, ядовитая дамочка эта журналистка, но не безграмотная, имеет право поставить свои тире, где ей хочется что-то выделить, чтобы до всех дошло и вызвало возмущение читателей.

Comment: На мой взгляд, все можно понять и принять, кроме (5). Невозможно представить интонацию, оправдывающую тире перед "что".  Я бы еще как-то согласился с тире после "но". Однако без тире куда естественней.

Comment: Согласна, что без тире естественнее и правильней, но речь идёт об уже написанной статье, вопрос не в том, как лучше, а как объяснить. Объяснить можно только интонационным тире. А вообще эта журналистка довольно грамотна (я посмотрела всю статью), тире - её конёк, такая уж эмоциональная. Её пунктуация похожа на цветаевскую, там тоже полно тире, и все интонационные.

Answer (score 1):

Парцелляция, интонационное тире – это вполне разрешенные и часто применяемые в журналистике приемы, особенно если нужно изобразить "накал страстей". В то же время, как мне кажется, есть какие-то **разумные ограничения**: так, одновременное применение парцелляции, интонационного тире и  присоединительных союзов может выглядеть как нечто искусственное и мало оправданное.  Текст в таких  случаях  художественной выразительности не приобретает, но становится  неудобным для чтения.  Другими словами, **во всём должно быть чувство меры и вкуса.**

**Примеры редактирования:**

1) Осень принесла новый виток напряженности и противостояния нижегородцев и городских властей, **причём** – с полного попустительства самой власти.

2) Осталось смахнуть слезу умиления да вздохнуть с чувством глубокого удовлетворения… Вот только мешает что-то, **и одна из возможных причин** – полная безнаказанность за незаконные выходки «несистемной оппозиции», возглавляющей жителей.

(Здесь "например"  – **смысловая неточность**: ведь непонятно, что мешает, можно только предполагать, что именно, а не приводить примеры.).

3) Хотя в близлежащих домах живёт несколько сотен человек, **то есть** – видео смотрят сами участники съемок да их заказчики.

4)Самое омерзительное, что за всей этой вакханалией стоят персонажи, хорошо известные – **как правоохранительным органам, так и горожанам** – своей неуёмной разрушительной энергией, своей плохой репутацией. **И – своими судимостями.**

5)Получил он два года условно, но по уголовной статье. Говорят, хотели вообще невменяемым признать, но покровители решили –  **это уже перебор.**

Comment: Так ведь автор просит не отредактировать, а обосновать тире в статье известной журналистки.

Comment: Обоснование здесь простое: все тире ИНТОНАЦИОННЫЕ. Вот, к примеру,  Розенталь пишет: «Такое тире, называемое интонационным, может отделять любую часть предложения». Это  можно воспринять как  полную свободу действий (даже перед союзом ЧТО возьму и поставлю тире). Но давайте прочитаем весь параграф: "Тире ставится для указания места разделения простого предложения на словесные группы, чтобы...". А дальше   указывается ЦЕЛЬ, то есть  для чего нужно это тире. Кстати,  парцелляция тоже должна быть осмысленной и обоснованной.

Comment: А вот  у "известной журналистки"  интонационное тире и парцелляция очень часть не у места, потому что  то же самое можно выразить без такого нагромождения  выразительных средств.  И я считаю, что  такое письмо служить образцом не может, поставленных задач не достигает,   а вызывает вполне обоснованные сомнения в грамотности автора. РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЕ  же приведено для того, чтобы  показать, как можно (и с моей точки зрения нужно) оформить этот текст.http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=94

Answer (score 0):

В большинстве случае такое тире - интонационное, соответствует а) речевому периоду или б) смысловой паузе на месте неожиданного поворота или противопоставления. Но тут надо отдельно с каждым примером разбираться. Они разные.

1) Не вижу оснований для постановки тире тут, даже "авторского". Они были бы, будь на месте точки перед "причем" запятая. Тогда тире зрительно оформляло бы конструкцию выделения. В последнем случае я иногда его ставлю, хотя, конечно, это некоторая авторская вольность. Но если "причем" перовое слово в предложении, тире это ничего не добавляет.

2) Вот тут тот случай, о котором я говорил выше. Запятая здесь невозможна, поскольку вводное слово стоит впереди уточняющей конструкции, к которой и относится. Изъятие это из общего правила обособления вводных связано с тем, что при обособлении запятыми возникала бы двусмысленность. Однако интуитивно какой знак обычно хочется поставит, выделяю вводное. Тире здесь как раз и есть факультативная, но разумная альтернатива простому пробелу.

3) Тире не нужно, см. 1)

4) О каком тире речь? Первое вводит уточнение, тут вопросов нет. Видимо, вопрос о втором. Второе стоит после союза в начале предложения, но который написан строчной буквой. Ясно, что ошибка есть. Либо нет точки перед союзом, либо сам союз с заглавной. В обоих случаях тире не требуется, хотя возможно как авторский интонационный знак (резкая, неожиданная смена тональности). Но я бы, пожалуй, не стал тут заниматься авторской пунктуацией.

5) Совершенно не поддается логическому объяснению, вообще никакому. Тут должна быть запятая.

Итого. Нет ни одного случая обязательного тире, в двух или трех - возможно, но только в одном (2) тире это выглядит стилистически содержательным.